# c# Solo insertar los registros que tienen la fecha mas alta

Tags: c#

actualmente de un directorio leo archivos csv y leo linea por linea y almaceno sus valores en una tabla. Eso funciona bien y lo hago mediante un StreamReader. El problema es que ahora requieren que solo inserte los registros que cuenten con la fecha mas alta.

Actualmente los CSV llegan de manera periodica mediante un FTP. La inserción funciona bien, pero no se como hacer para que solo se inserten los registros de la ultima fecha.

[image: Estructura de la base.]

Ahora por ejemplo como se ve en la imagen inserto los datos de los csv desde el 3/06 hasta el 2/07. Lo que yo necesitaria hacer es que solo se inserte en este caso el del 2/07 y posteriormente cuando sea mañana que se pise el del 2/07 y ingrese el del 3/07.

Les adjunto el código, queria usar la funcion MAX de SQL para obtener la mayor fecha y solo insertar esos. Otra idea que se me ocurre es ordenar la fecha de stock pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Proyecto SFTP -SQL- 
Pedidos_Poti\LOCAL_DOWNLOAD\", "Open25*") ;

                    //  Console.WriteLine("cantidad de archivos que empiezan con Open25 son:... {0}.", dirs.Length);


                    foreach (String dir in dirs)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir))
                        {
                            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                            {
                                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine(line);
                                string[] values = line.Split('|');


                                Stock items = new Stock();

                                items.Fecha_Stock = values[0];
                                items.Sucursal = values[1];
                                items.Cod_Art = values[2];
                                items.Ean = values[3];
                                items.Stock_Actual = values[4];
                                items.Art_En_Promocion = values[5];
                                items.Fecha_Ini_Promo = values[6];
                                items.Fecha_Fin_Promo = values[7];

                                string converted = items.Fecha_Stock.Substring(0, 2) + "/" +
                                                   items.Fecha_Stock.Substring(2, 2) + "/" +
                                                   items.Fecha_Stock.Substring(4, 4);

                                lista_stock.Add(items);

                                string converted2 = items.Fecha_Ini_Promo.Substring(0, 2) + "/" +
                                                    items.Fecha_Ini_Promo.Substring(2, 2) + "/" +
                                                    items.Fecha_Ini_Promo.Substring(4, 4);

                                string converted3 = items.Fecha_Fin_Promo.Substring(0, 2) + "/" +
                                                    items.Fecha_Fin_Promo.Substring(2, 2) + "/" +
                                                    items.Fecha_Fin_Promo.Substring(4, 4);

                                String insertar = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T001_IMPORTAR_STOCK Where Cod_Articulo = @param3 AND Fecha_Stock = @param1) BEGIN  INSERT INTO [dbo].[T001_IMPORTAR_STOCK]([Fecha_Stock], [Sucursal], [Cod_Articulo], [EAN], [Stock_Actual], [Art_En_Promocion], [Fecha_Ini_Promo], [Fecha_Fin_Promo]) VALUES(@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5, @param6, @param7, @param8)END";

                                sqlConnection.Close();
                                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertar, sqlConnection))
                                {
                                    sqlConnection.Open();
                                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = converted;
                                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(items.Sucursal);
                                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(items.Cod_Art);
                                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = items.Ean;
                                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param5", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(items.Stock_Actual);
                                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param6", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(items.Art_En_Promocion);
                                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param7", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = converted2;
                                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param8", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = converted3;

                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                }
                                sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Pues, en un ETL tendrías que leer todos los registros para saber cuál es la fecha más alta. De ahí ya podrías crear un subconjunto con los registros de esa fecha e insertar en la tabla destino

Comment: No podria ordenar el objeto items.Fecha_Stock y obtener el máximo y solo insertar los que cumplen esa condición? Pasa que si lo hago dentro de un foreach pierdo el contexto de la variable.

Comment: Estás usando readline, asi que vas archivo por archivo y línea por línea en cada archivo. Que además es más amable con la memoria porque no debería cargar todo el archivo en memoria

Comment: Ahora estoy utilizando Directory.GetFiles para obtener los archivos a leer, habra una forma para decir que solo me lea el ultimo? no lo encuentro :(. Pero gracias por tirarme una idea :D

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción que tienes es usar una tabla temporal o una table intermedia para seleccionar la fecha más alta luego de insertar desde el csv. De esta forma puedes usar la función max(fecha).

Dependiendo de la cantidad de registros que venga en el csv, hacer esta comparación antes de insertar puede requerir muchos recursos.

No obstante, de todas formas estás recorriendo todo el archivo linea a linea para hacer la inserción, así que puedes ir comparando la fecha en cada vuelta, y cuando encuentres una fecha más reciente guardar los valores de este registro en un objeto. Al final de bucle deberías tener en este objeto el registro de la fecha más reciente.